# Editable Fields in Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a column that needs to be editable by user in interactive grid.

However, I want that user can only choose from 2 static values. Is there a way I can implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 'Select List' or 'Switch' for column type, instead of 'Text Field'.

Then associate the relevant List of Values, either from a static list, a SQL query, or pre-defined shared component.

Alternatively/additionally, you could have a validation on that column to check for those specific values.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert column type to "Select List" or "Radio Group", and then you can define "Static Values" as "List of Values".